# Eclipse WAS V7.0 Dev Tools wsimport error

Tags: eclipse, web-services, websphere, jax-ws, wsimport

I'm trying to generate a "Top down EJB Web Service" implementation from a WSDL with WAS V7.0 Developer Tools. (Server runtime WAS 7.0, web service runtime IBM WebSphere JAX-WS.) After selecting my EJB and EAR projects and specifying further options, I always get the following error, regardless of my options:

```
Errors occurred during wsimport.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/tools/internal/ws/wscompile/WsimportTool
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.ast.ws.jaxws.emitter.jdk6.command.AbstractEmitterCommand.loadClass(AbstractEmitterCommand.java:166)
at com.ibm.ast.ws.jaxws.emitter.jdk6.command.WsImportCommand.execute(WsImportCommand.java:113)
at com.ibm.ast.ws.jaxws.emitter.command.WsImportCommand.execute(WsImportCommand.java:81)
at com.ibm.ast.ws.jaxws.creation.command.WsimportNonUIThreadCommand$RunCmdInNonUIThread.run(WsimportNonUIThreadCommand.java:284)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 16 more
```

Going through the exact same steps in Rational Application Developer 7.5.1, I can successfully generate an EJB web service implementation with an HTTP router module for my WSDL. So I think this problem might be related to WAS Developer Tools.

Do you guys have any idea why I'm getting this error? Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you,
Csaba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't enough to configure Eclipse to use IBM's SDK for projects, I had to start Eclipse using IBM's JVM. I've edited eclipse's config file (eclipse.ini) and added IBM's JRE.

```
openFile
-vm
...\IBM\WebSphere7\AppServer\java\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
...
```

[Reference](http://websphereissues.wordpress.com/2012/07/13/secure-servers-are-only-supported-with-ibm-jre-6-0-or-above-error-in-eclipse-ide/)

Comment: The link in your answer is broken. In general, [it is preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference, for this reason. Please update this answer with relevant information, or remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using the WAS 7.0 JVM when you run the `wsimport`.  You may have several JVMs on your workstation.  The JVM under `<was install>/java` is the one you want in your PATH ahead of all others when using the command.

Comment: Yes, I'm using WebSphere's Java SDK, just forgot to mention. Good point anyway, thanks.